# Is it possible to disable third-party cookies while on my site on behalf of users?

Tags: cookies, webserver

I have a website that loads a resource from another website. I've been able to determine that:

- The third-party website places cookies on the user's browser.
- If I disable third-party cookies in my browser settings, the third-party website is no longer able to place cookies on the browser.
- The resource still works properly.

I'm wondering if there is some kind of header or other directive I can deliver from my website that will have the same effect for my users as if they had disabled third-party cookies, but which doesn't require them to go and monkey around with their settings.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this. If so could you add your insights ?

Comment: @StormBr34ker No, I didn't. Instead, I included instructions in my site's privacy policy for disabling third-party cookies. Definitely a lame workaround, but better than nothing.

Comment: Oh okay @Brian Rak. Thanks . I used a Google Tag Manager for blocking most of the cookies . Although - I could not find a definitive (single shot) way to block the ones that are set by the framework or plugins or etc.

Comment: Does this help: [How to block third-party cookies](https://cookie-script.com/how-to-block-third-party-cookies.html)? It really depends on how you are accessing this third-party site/source. Could you give more details please? e.g. what language/framework you are using, maybe a code snippet of how you are accessing this site/source

Comment: Thanks for the link! From what I was able to tell, it looks like that is a script that essentially prevents the loading of other scripts on your page that you've decorated with a `data-cookiescript` attribute unless the user has opted to accept cookies. What I was looking for was a little different. I still want to load and run the script from the third-party website. I simply want to prevent that script from creating cookies on the client. Basically exactly the same behavior as if the user had disabled third-party cookies in their preferences.

Comment: Would there be a possibility of simply duplicating that script and then modifying it to remove the creation of cookies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, it has been impossible to prevent your browser from including cookies in your HTTP requests. However, recently, few new ways to fetch resources were added to browsers.

- **Using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):** `fetch` ignores `Set-Cookie` in responses, and does not include `Cookie` unless specified.
- **Using ES6 (ES2015) modules:** `<script type="module" ...>` without its `crossorigin` attribute will not send `Cookie`. It doesn't work for non-module scripts, and the server (not yours, the one serving the file) must be configured to serve the file with valid CORS headers. Scripts imported with `import * from blah.com/script.js` will also behave in the same way. Follow the [link](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/) for more info.
- **Setting `crossorigin="anonymous"`:** Resource elements such as `script`, `img` and `style` with `crossorigin="anonymous"` will not include `Cookie` headers in subsequent requests.

But these all work by using [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), and if the resource server is configured to disallow requests without credentials (cookies, and other headers), they won't work. You will likely get 404 or other errors instead.

If you are worried about third-party cookies, it's usually better to serve statics from your own server, or cookie-free servers like most CDNs.

Browsers such as Firefox and Safari disable third party cookies by default, and Chrome is the last modern browser that still allows third party cookies by default as of Jan 2020. But even [Chrome](https://www.theverge.com/2020/1/14/21064698/google-third-party-cookies-chrome-two-years-privacy-safari-firefox) is phasing out of third party cookies.