# My telegram website log in widget stopped working. How to set third-party cookie for the recently updated browsers?

Tags: telegram-bot, third-party-cookies

I integrated telegram login widget for my website several months ago.
It worked like a charm.
But it stopped working today.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Sd9.png)
IMO, the reason is that my Chrome browser has been updated recently, and banned third-party cookies.
Even telegram community has no solution for this yet.
Anyone can help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telegram responded so quickly to the changes of modern browsers' updates.
They implemented overcoming third-party cookies for telegram login widget.

For more information, you can refer this.
[Is it possible to disable third-party cookies while on my site on behalf of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371190/is-it-possible-to-disable-third-party-cookies-while-on-my-site-on-behalf-of-user)