# Set a cookie policy based on a domain whitelist

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm making a website which loads images from various sources, without knowing which these sources can be.

Some of these image hosts do set cookies when requesting an image (e.g. Imgur) even though this cookie is not necessary.

Is it possible (using a HTML header or some javascript) to add a whitelist to my website which states which domains are trusted and are allowed to set cookies, blocking all other third-party cookies?

Comment: Permission control? I don't know what you mean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371190/is-it-possible-to-disable-third-party-cookies-while-on-my-site-on-behalf-of-user